# Adding a loading bar while php script is preparing a file for download

Tags: php, progress-bar, text-files

I'm a newbie to php but have managed to create a page I call "welcome.php" that takes your first and last name from a form, then puts these in a simple text file and sends it back to you for download:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST) {

    header("Content-Type: application/txt");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="welcome.txt"');
    echo "Welcome, ";
    echo $_POST['firstName']. " " . $_POST['lastName']; 

    // exit the script to make the form not appear in the downloaded file
    exit;
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name:  <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
```

What I want to do is to add a progress bar while this text file is being generated, which reaches 100% when the "save file" dialogue box pops up. I *know* in this case the load time is very short, but I will be modifying it later to make much larger text files. I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction or provide a couple of lines of code to help, bearing in my mind I've only been learning php for 2 days. I believe you can use something called flush, but I'm not sure how to integrate this into my page. Thanks!

Note that my page also has a slight glitch in that the text file also outputs the html of the form, does anyone know how to stop this happening?

Comment: The text file contains the form because after the `echo` calls, the PHP parser comes out of the `if` statement, and then `echo`s out all of the HTML. You need to add an `else` to make it say if `$_POST` then send text file, else continue to show HTML page.

Comment: @Alex: I fixed the small problem.

Comment: so I think I've fixed it by echoing the html like so? 'else { echo "<form action = ........</form>";}

Comment: No, you don't need to `echo` the whole form, you can do it just like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/11ddd1fde7cf28452150).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PHP doesn't provide such a feature.

To show a progress-bar, you might try this:

- While executing the long-running file generation process, save a **percentage-done value** in the current **user session**
- On the page, which shows the download form, add an **iFrame** which calls a **progress.php** script
- The progress.php script needs to generate webpage, which needs to reload auto-magically
- The progress.php script needs to read the current progress-value from the session and **draw a progress bar graphics**, which visually represents the progress.

While this is a PHP-only solution, you might well prepare another one using JS / AJAX.

The HTML auto-reload should like like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://myServer.com/progress.php">
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm just having a bit of trouble finding the "percentage-done" function. Once I get that, am I right in thinking it's just a case of calling it every, say, 200ms, then passing its value to something like the jqueryui progress bar like Iony suggested below? I really appreciate your contribution!

Comment: Have a look here: http://db.org/demo/2003/02/17/progress-bar/ . Sorry. no other source handy right now.

Comment: Additionally, PHP's GD library is your friend: http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php

Comment: Thanks for the examples, however the progress bar I was thinking of was intended to show the progress of the server processing the file, instead of the progress of the user inputting data. When I click on submit, the favicon at the top of the screen (in firefox) shows a grey anticlockwise loading wheel until the save file dialogue box pops up. I think the percentage bar may be a bit beyond me currently, so is there a way to mimic this weel in the browser? I have a wheel gif, and know how to show and hide it, I just need to know how to hide it when the dialogue box pops up?

Comment: My hint proposes a way to show server-progress. The script reads data from the session - on the server - and then prepares the graphics.

Comment: I see that in the progress bar example, the percentage complete is calculated by writing <?=$done?>/<?=$total?>. But total is just the number of steps in the form, and done is just the number of steps completed so far. Say if my form inputs a single word from the user, then my php adds a number to the end, loops a thousand times, then outputs the text file (name1, name2, ...,name1000). Would I track the current progress by adding a line of code to the end of my loop along the lines of (current iteration)/1000 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/ it is JavaScript based and you can send your progress via AJAX, like Stefan said.

Comment: ... as long as JS is enabled. Should be available on any browser these days.